# Store/restore opengl full state

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I need to store the full opengl state set by some client code, do my stuff and reset it. I need to do it for opengl 2.0, opengl 3.2+, opengl es 2.0 and opengl es 3.0

1. opengl 2.0: I think I can use pushAttri/popAttri ALL_ATTRIB_BITS and this should work
2. opengl 3.0: The pushAttri/popAttri have been deprecated. I think I can do something like

   glGetIntegerv(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, &m_LineHint);

and reset it later. But I will have to do this for everything. Is there something like ALL_ATTRIB_BITS which I can use. is there some other method to achieve this.

3. opengl es 2.0 and opengl es 3.0: I think the same

   glGetIntegerv(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, &m_LineHint);

should work here also or is there some other way?

I also want to know the performance implications of storing/resetting the full state.

Comment: How about creating a custom OpenGL context just for your code? Switch to that context for your stuff, draw it and switch back.